# PHP $_SESSION[] is not store right value in firefox only but on other browser working perfectly

Tags: php, wordpress, session, firefox

I am trying to store current post id into SESSION in wordpress. But it's not working only in firefox . On other browser like google crome,Safari, Opera mini is working perfectly.

When i am trying to get the current post id SESSION always store next post id (But only in firefox).

Here is the code i used:

I called the session_start(); into my header.php file

on single.php file

```
$project_current_id = get_the_id();    

$_SESSION['project_p_id']=$project_current_id;
```

On other file i just try to get the value with 
  " echo $_SESSION['project_p_id']; "

Comment: `Session` has nothing to do with browsers. But, it's dependent on the `cookies`. So check if your firefox is updated and working with cookies or check with some other system.